# Reversing minificiation/obfuscation of CSS styles on web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-scraping, jss

It is normal for web pages to sometimes have obfuscated/minified CSS classes. This has the (perhaps intentional) side effect of preventing page scraping due do the randomized class names.

The page is well-defined - while the html is different on every page load, the rendered page always looks the same. For example, there is always a title at `font-size: 20px; color: black;`, or a description is always `font-size: 15px; line-height: 1.5;` and so on...

Is there a process to un-randomize the class names? 
Or a way to select elements based on rendered style (e.g. `font-size: 20px; color: black;`)?

```html
<div tabindex="0" class="styles__Header-sc-120s71t-1 bVobsP">
    <h6 class="jss85xpic jsspbfkgl jssfrl2gs" style="max-width: 100%;">Title</h6>
    <div class="styles__Description-sc-120s71t-2 cilEqp">
        <p class="jss85xpic jsspbfkgl jssou361l" style="max-width: 100%;">Description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="styles__ItemsList-sc-120s71t-3 gyRIpM">
        <div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" role="button" tabindex="0" class="styles__Wrapper-sc-1xl58bi-2 gKTcIQ" style="max-width: 100%;">
            <div class="styles__FlexContainer-sc-1xl58bi-4 bLvOGI">
                <div class="styles__TextWrapper-sc-1xl58bi-9 liomPZ">
                    <div class="styles__Title-sc-1xl58bi-5 eqysaj">
                        <h3 class="jss85xpic jsspbfkgl jssws5ijf" style="max-width: 100%;"><span itemprop="name">Item 1</span></h3>
                    </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would the de-obfuscator know the intent of the original author?  As for your second question, you could script this by using the calculated style.

Comment: That's a good point, it wouldn't be possible to de-obfuscate the class names. What do you mean "script this by using the calculated style"? Is there a way to select based on calculated style, or compute the calculated style of an element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the classes are truly randomizing every time I'm not sure what you could do there. And searching by styling would require brute-force checking every element's computed style.

If what you're looking for is a way to traverse this HTML: is the shape always consistent? You could use a combination of tag selectors, "immediate child" selectors [`>`], and "begins with" selectors [`^`] (for those `styles__***` classes) to try to find the elements you're looking for.

E.g.: the title would be `[class^="styles__Header"] > h6`. The description would be `[class^="styles__Description"] > p`.

Comment: The shape is always consistent. Using a complex CSS selector sounds like it could work. Although it may be inefficient, brute-forcing a document with millions of elements wouldn't take more than a few seconds. Is it possible to search by styling or determine what the final style of an element is?

Comment: I don't know of any way to specifically search by styling. I think you'd just have to loop through literally every element (maybe try at least filtering by some specifics like tag name)  and call [`getComputedStyle(el)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) and check. But that'd be super fragile. If the shape is consistent I'd say your best bet is definitely to work off that.

Comment: OP - the term for what SamVK is doing at the end is attribute = value css selectors and then using the ^ (starts with) **operator** in case you want to be able to look those up: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors